# How to download a file from a AWS S3 bucket in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my iOS app, I try to download a file from an AWS S3 bucket. Here is what I tried:

1. I initialize AWSMobileClient:

```swift
import AWSMobileClient
import AWSS3

let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1,
    credentialsProvider: AWSMobileClient.default())
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState: UserState?, error: Error?) in

    if (userState != nil)
    {
        print("Initialize OK : \(userState.debugDescription)")
    }
    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("Initialize error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

I got:

```
"initialize OK : Optional(AWSMobileClient.UserState.guest)"
```

2. Now I try to download a file:

```swift
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print("Progress : \(progress)")
    })
}
                
let completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock = {
    (task: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask, url: URL?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("End download 1")
        })
}
                
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("100.ogg")
                
let transferUtility: AWSS3TransferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
transferUtility.download(
    to: fileURL,
    bucket: "my-s3-bucket",
    key: "100.ogg",
    expression: expression,
    completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
                        
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error download : \(error)")
        }
        if let result = task.result {
            print("Result : \(result.debugDescription)")
        }
        print("End download 2 : \(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString))")
        return nil
    }
```

I got:

```
"Result : <AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask: 0x6000020bd4d0>
"End download 2 : false"
```

I don't get any progress, and I also don't get the `"End download 1"`

So basically, I dont get any error, but it does look like nothing has been downloaded. Also, on a side note, it works well with the Android version of my app, so it's very likely that there is an error in my code.

So what should I change to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly irrelevant but this is wrong `fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString)`  should be `fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path)`

Comment: @WarrenBurton Oh ok, well I'm an iOS beginner, so maybe that's my mistake, I'll try later on, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the example above is actually working, But I had to:

- change `fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString))` by `fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path))`
- check if file exists in the first `completionHandler` (where I wrote `print("End download 1")`)